# Inserir se não existir ou Atualizar se já existir no Mysql?

Tags: mysql

Como posso no MySql dar um `INSERT` ou um `UPDATE` se a linha em questão já existir ou não?

Tentei da seguinte forma mas não funcionou:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM configs WHERE id_serie = :id) 
           UPDATE configs 
                SET dados = :valor  
                WHERE id_serie = :id 
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO configs (id_serie, dados) VALUES (:id, :valor)
```

Porém não funcionou, li sobre o `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` mas como a coluna que uso para verificar no caso `id_serie` não é a chave primaria da tabela, imaginei que não fosse funcionar, ou funciona?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode tentar utilizar o `REPLACE INTO`. Ele é semelhante ao `INSERT`, porém se o registro a ser inserido possua o mesmo valor de uma chave primária ou de um índice único, o registro existente é apagado e o novo registro é inserido.

```
REPLACE INTO configs (id_serie, dados) VALUES (:id, :valor)
```

Caso queira dar uma olhada na documentação: [Mysql - REPLACE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html)

Comment: Mas neste caso, se eu alterar só uma coluna, o novo registro vai obter todos os valores das outras colunas antigas e inserir no novo atualizando somente o que eu preciso?

Comment: Não. Se você deixar alguma coluna sem informar, você perderá o valor desses campos.

Comment: Não me parece muito seguro fazer desta forma, acho que vou acabar tendo que combinar um pouco de PHP com esse UPDATE / INSERT

Answer (score 1):

Tente uma das formas abaixo.

Atribuindo em uma variável o total de registros encontrados.

```
declare @total int;
set @total = (select count(*) from configs where id_serie = :id)

if (@total > 0)
    update anime_configs set dados = :valor 
    where id_serie = :id 
else 
    insert into configs (id_serie, dados) values (:id, :valor)
```

Ou verificando a quantidade de registros afetados no `update`. Se o update der erro (porque já existe) então será retornado zero registros, e com isso, chamará o `insert`.

```
update anime_configs set dados = :valor where id_serie = :id
if (@@rowcount = 0)
    insert into configs (id_serie, dados) values (:id, :valor)
```

Comment: Isso funciona pra MySql? Testei ambas aqui e da erro

Comment: E qual o erro em ambas?

Comment: Já tentou assim (ps: não sei se funciona)? `IF(INSERT INTO configs (dados) 
       SELECT :valor WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM config WHERE id_serie = :id)) 
ELSE
       UPDATE configs SET dados = :valor WHERE id_serie = :id;`

Answer (score 0):

O mysql possui um parâmetro que verifica se o registro existe e caso exista vc poderá dar um update. segue o exemplo.

```
INSERT INTO cliente (id, nome) VALUES (10, 'nome do cliente') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE nome = 'nome do cliente';
```

você poderá atualizar vários campos separando por "," Vírgula. a única obrigação é a chave única (primary key).